# Why cant I remove this border with CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

I have two questions I seek your help with:

1. I am trying to remove the grey border using CSS but can't seem to remove it.

   My code is:

   ```
   <p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " style="border:4px solid #ccc; padding: 12px;">
     <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
       <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>
       29.00
     </span>
     <a href="?add-to-cart=511" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart"
       data-product_id="511" data-product_sku="plan1" aria-label="Add “Plan 1” to your cart" rel="nofollow">
       Add to cart
     </a>
   </p>
   ```

   My CSS is:

   ```
   p.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline {
     border:0px;
   }

   span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
     display:none
   }
   ```

   [Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lindychen/prfxy6mw/2/).
   Can someone please let me know why my CSS code does not work?
2. In Chrome developer tools, is there a way to easily copy the CSS selector?

   For example, after pointing out that [this is the selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVtSD.png).
   Is there a way to easily copy the "p.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline"?

   Right now I type it out manually myself. I am pretty sure that there should be a way to copy it and paste it directly?

Comment: To copy the CSS in the developer tools, select the element you want to copy the CSS for and then highlight what you want in the styles tab. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvbVv.png)

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks. But then when I do your method, it will not have the stuff at the front such as p. a. span. etc

Comment: Adding the element before a class or id is usually not necessary, unless you need it for CSS specificity reasons or want to distinguish between different elements that have the same class. [Here is a CSS Specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your HTML code you have inline css for border in html `p` tag

```
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span><a href="?add-to-cart=511" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="511" data-product_sku="plan1" aria-label="Add “Plan 1” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a></p>
```

or you can add important to css like this:

```
p.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline {border:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of css [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rules

You are adding border style inline in `p` tag which has more specificity than css selector.

To fix this, remove the border style from the inline and apply it using another css selector.

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt3r9qwx/)

```css
p.product.woocommerce {
  border: 4px solid #ccc;
  padding: 12px;
}

p.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline {
  border: 0px;
}

span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span><a href="?add-to-cart=511" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="511"
    data-product_sku="plan1" aria-label="Add “Plan 1” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove border css style from style attribute

```
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " style="padding: 12px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>29.00</span><a href="?add-to-cart=511" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="511" data-product_sku="plan1" aria-label="Add “Plan 1” to your cart" rel="nofollow">Add to cart</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

add !important

```css
p.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline {border:none!important;}
```